# Procedure to Search String with split

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, stored-procedures, split

I need to Search a String in multiple Column With OR Condition & also want to split String by SPACE. Ex. If User Search 'Software Developer' then a simple Query will be like

```
Select * from TableName Where Col1 LIKE '%Software%' OR Col2 LIKE '%Software%' OR Col3 LIKE '%Software%' OR Col1 LIKE '%Developer%' OR Col2 LIKE '%Developer%' OR Col3 LIKE '%Developer%'
```

In Procedure should be One Parameter. Something like

```
ProcedureName 'Software Developer'
```

I can work on above Query but I need to know, Is there any Simple, Fast and better query which i can do.

Comment: based on your question, what you really need is [FTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Comment: I think i can't use FTS in GoDaddy Shared Hosting Database. !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you thin you can use the query like

> Select * from Table where ( col1 + col2 + col3 like '%Software%') OR (col1 + col2 + col3 like '%Engineer%')

Comment: I was using this same query for one of application related retreival and it was workign fine. Could you show me the SQL you generated?

Comment: Your solution will not work if  the column only had `Software` without `Developer`

Comment: @ughai When sending the search text ensure that the correct prefixing and suffixing is done along with spaces replacement. I am doing that currently for our employee table where thre are more than 20 employees with same first name and last name but with a different middle name,

Comment: Based on the OP's requirement to strip the search string and search them independently, your solution will only work if parts of the entire string are present in all the columns. instead what the OP wants is that even if a single word in the search string matches, return the row. it is different from when you want to search a word "Kumar" against first last and middle name to see if it comes up in any of those columns

Comment: But in my case its not sure that both word will be in same row. may be it can and may be not

Comment: @ughai Thanks for pointing that out. I surely did not get the Question fully.

Comment: @Yusuf do you think that you can modify the where condition as     'where ( col1 + col2 + col3 like '%Software%') OR  (col1 + col2 + col3 like '%Engineer%')'

Comment: @yusuf Glad that I could give inputs

Comment: Thanks Kumar C Its Done. Now i have to use Dynamic Where condition & split the Search Text Because i will take only one Parameter in Stored Procedure.?

Comment: You'd be in trouible with this if any of the columns had nulls.
You'll need to COALESCE each of them.

Comment: I'll Use COALESCE but any field will never be NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     dbo.JD_tblJob.EmployerID, dbo.JD_tblJob.PostDate, dbo.JD_tblJob.JobID, dbo.JD_tblJob.JobTitle, dbo.JD_tblJob.JobDescr, dbo.JD_tblJob.MinWorkExp, 
                  dbo.JD_tblJob.MaxWorkExp, dbo.JD_tblJob.MinSalary, dbo.JD_tblJob.MaxSalary, dbo.JD_tblJob.HideSalary, dbo.JD_tblJob.NoOfVacancies, 
                  dbo.JD_tblJob.JobLocation, dbo.JD_tblJob.Active, dbo.JD_tblEmployer.CompanyName, tblKeySkill.fldName AS KeySkillName, 
                  tblFuncArea.fldName AS FuncAreaName FROM dbo.JD_tblJob INNER JOIN dbo.JD_tblMaster AS tblFuncArea ON dbo.JD_tblJob.FuncAreaID = tblFuncArea.ID INNER JOIN dbo.JD_tblMaster AS tblKeySkill ON dbo.JD_tblJob.KeySkillID = tblKeySkill.ID INNER JOIN dbo.JD_tblEmployer ON dbo.JD_tblJob.EmployerID = dbo.JD_tblEmployer.ID WHERE (dbo.JD_tblJob.JobTitle LIKE '%Engineer%') OR (tblKeySkill.fldName LIKE '%Engineer%') OR (tblFuncArea.fldName LIKE '%Engineer%') OR (dbo.JD_tblJob.JobTitle LIKE '%Software%') OR (tblKeySkill.fldName LIKE '%Software%') OR (tblFuncArea.fldName LIKE '%Software%')
```

Its giving me result but below not showing any row

```
SELECT     dbo.JD_tblJob.EmployerID, dbo.JD_tblJob.PostDate, dbo.JD_tblJob.JobID, dbo.JD_tblJob.JobTitle, dbo.JD_tblJob.JobDescr, dbo.JD_tblJob.MinWorkExp, dbo.JD_tblJob.MaxWorkExp, dbo.JD_tblJob.MinSalary, dbo.JD_tblJob.MaxSalary, dbo.JD_tblJob.HideSalary, dbo.JD_tblJob.NoOfVacancies, dbo.JD_tblJob.JobLocation, dbo.JD_tblJob.Active, dbo.JD_tblEmployer.CompanyName, tblKeySkill.fldName AS KeySkillName, tblFuncArea.fldName AS FuncAreaName FROM dbo.JD_tblJob INNER JOIN dbo.JD_tblMaster AS tblFuncArea ON dbo.JD_tblJob.FuncAreaID = tblFuncArea.ID INNER JOIN dbo.JD_tblMaster AS tblKeySkill ON dbo.JD_tblJob.KeySkillID = tblKeySkill.ID INNER JOIN dbo.JD_tblEmployer ON dbo.JD_tblJob.EmployerID = dbo.JD_tblEmployer.ID WHERE dbo.JD_tblJob.JobTitle + tblKeySkill.fldName + tblFuncArea.fldName LIKE '%Engineer%Software%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--What you are searching for
DECLARE @yourSearch varchar(50) = 'Software Developer'

DECLARE @strs varchar(200)
SET @strs = REPLACE(@yourSearch,' ','.')
DECLARE @searchWord1 varchar(50);
DECLARE @searchWord2 varchar(50);

--Split search into 2 words
SELECT
  @searchWord1 = PARSENAME(@strs,1),
  @searchWord2 = PARSENAME(@strs,2)

--Do the select
SELECT * FROM TableName 
WHERE 
  CONCAT(COALESCE( Col1, ''),COALESCE( Col2, ''),COALESCE( Col3, '')) LIKE '%' + @searchWord1 +  '%'
  OR 
  CONCAT(COALESCE( Col1, ''),COALESCE( Col2, ''),COALESCE( Col3, '')) LIKE '%' + @searchWord2 +  '%'
```